# Is it safe to pass BuildContext to family provider as a parameter using flutter riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Is it safe to pass buildContext in flutter as a parameter to a family provider using flutter riverpod?

Comment: How would you use it? Generally I would say no, especially if you store it, but there might be a case where it makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it safe? Yes. Nothing terrible will happen

Is it a bad practice? Also yes. Your providers should be independent from the UI. And relying on `BuildContext` may make it difficult to obtain your provider's state in a different place.

Comment: no, I just ran into a usecase where I want the buildcontext to be passed to a provider which will return a proper locale based on different conditions

the mere use of context is  S.of(context).title;   // for example

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass build context in the riverpod. Build context should be local to the screen. Don't make it global.